# Help with complex model formula in lmer (lme4) for R

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

Most examples about `lmer` formula description in R target rather simple study designs. However, sometimes one is confronted with more complex designs and there is no documentation about a general rule to formula-construction. For instance, how would I formulate the following design:

- 15 subjects (`ID`) treated as between random effect in 3 groups (`Group`) treated as between fixed effect (but would be nice to treat as another between random effect)
- 2 within effects (`Position`, `Size`)
- 1 between random factor primary eye (`Eye`)

To elaborate about the design as requested:
15 subjects participated in an HCI user study and were exposed to targets at different Positions of different Sizes. The Time to recognition was measured as the dependent variable. Between Groups we also randomized the visual appearance of targets and delays for display, which was necessary to randomize but only between groups to limit the number of overall factors. However, Group may thus have introduced a random effect.

I tried:

```
lmer(Time ~ Group*Position*Size + (1|ID) + (1|Eye) + (1|Position:ID) + (1|Size:ID))
```

However, with this formula I'm not sure:

- whether `Group` should also appear in the definition of `1|Position` and `1|Size` as it is actually nested not only within `id` but `id/Group`
- similar question as above for the random factor `Eye`
- how I would go about defining `Group` as random between factor instead of fixed between factor as the group sampling happened randomly

Comment: What do you mean by "random fixed factor"? Also, why do you say "treated as fixed effect or random effect"? That's a big difference; the distinction is the main point of mixed models, are you indifferent to which is used? Can you say more about your situation, your experimental setup, & your data?

Comment: @gung, thank you for your comment! I made the required adjustments. Hope to make myself clearer now.